# How to add multiple arrays to a subarray?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following three arrays of objects:

**First Array:** `$array1`

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => world
           )
)
```

**Second Array:** `$array2`

```
Array (
    [count] => 1
)
```

**Third Array:** `$array3`

```
Array (
    [KM] => 2
)
```

I want to add the associative elements from `$array2` and `$array3` into the subarray at `$array1[0]`.

**Desired output:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => world
            [count] => 1
            [KM] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: is `array_merge()` not working for some reason?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php should do exactly what you want

Comment: @Don'tPanic no it is not working for me

Comment: I think I can guess why, but we would need to see how you are trying to use it in order to know for sure.

Comment: Array merge is not working for me

Comment: Array merge output:   Array
(
    [KM] => 2
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => world
          
        )

    [1] => 1
)

Comment: Do you see the arrays, `array_merge` will result in different array structure that the desired one... See array_walk or use standard for/foreach looping mechanisms to build the desired array structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge these two arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842524/how-to-merge-these-two-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would use array_merge()

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(array("id" => 1, "name" => "world")); 
    $array2 = array("KM" => 2); 
    $array3 = array("count" => 1); 

    print_r(array(array_merge($array1[0], $array2, $array3))); 
?>
```

Which would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => world
            [KM] => 2
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_merge](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is the function you've been looking for

Sample code:

```
$output_array[0] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2, $array3));
print_r($output_array);
```

Comment: Direct array merge will not produce desired output.

Comment: `$array1[0]` is another array, please check the updated answer(with a demo code) @Rolice

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the desired output:

```
<?php

$array1 = array(array("id" => 1, "name" => "world"));
$array2 = array("KM" => 2); 
$array3 = array("count" => 1); 

$array1[0] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2, $array3);
print_r($array1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge()` will merge arrays. Problem is, the structure of your `$array1` differs from the others. You have an array inside an array. To produce the desired output as specified you would need this:

```
$array4 = array(
    0 => array_merge($array1[0], $array2, $array3)
);
```

But I believe you want something more like this:

```
$array4 = array_merge($array1[0], $array2, $array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )**
Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.